# WebBrowser Object under other objects

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, browser, kinect-sdk

I have a `WebBrowser` object in my WPF GUI. I want to use this object with the Kinect.
I use Kinect SDK 1.7, Visual Studio 2012, and I configure the `WebBrowser` object in IE10 emulation. 
The problem is that the `WebBrowser` object is always over every other object, even if I set its zIndex to lower value.

My aim is to see the *hand* of the `KinectSensorChooser` (binding with `KinectRegion`) over `WebBrowser` object.

I also tried to use other objects but they always appear under the `WebBrowser` object.

How I can put the `WebBrowser` object under other ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WPF Web Browser control is technically a wrapped WinForms WebBrowser Control, so it is rendered in the WinForms layer, which is always above the WPF layer.you can use  [Awesomium.NET](http://wiki.awesomium.net/getting-started/redist.html) Browser instead IE Browser or try Using [SetWindowRgn](http://www.flounder.com/setwindowrgn.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your kinectRegion  into a Popup control. Here is my code:

<--   WebBrowser Name="webMain"  Height="331" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1049" >

<--   Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=webMain}" Placement= "Center"  IsOpen="true"  Width="800" Height="340"  VerticalOffset="0"  HorizontalOffset="0" AllowsTransparency="True" Margin="103,0,275,360"

```
  <k:KinectRegion Grid.Row="1" x:Name="kinectRegion">
            ....
  </k:KinectRegion>
```

<--/Popup>